# Error when trying to create a table in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mysql and I was trying to create a basic table but I am getting one error that I can't figure out.

Heres the create table statement that I wrote

```
CREATE TABLE user (user_id varchar(50), name varchar(50), Yelping_since date, PRIMARY KEY(user_id);
```

heres the error that i get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'' at line 1
```

Comment: First parenthesis is unclosed.

Answer (score 1):

you just missed a closing bracket

```
CREATE TABLE user (user_id varchar(50), name varchar(50), Yelping_since date, PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ")" before the semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this dawg

```html
CREATE TABLE user (user_id varchar(50), name varchar(50), Yelping_since date, PRIMARY KEY(user_id))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you started mysql as root.

EDIT: 
try this instead:

```
CREATE TABLE user (user_id int NOT NULL, name varchar(50), Yelping_since date, PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
```